# In android TableLayout shrinkColumns appears to be the default attribute even if not explicitly stated

Tags: android, layout, android-tablelayout

In the following code, there are two tableLayouts with 3 columns each -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1">

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="test1"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="test2"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="test3"/>

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1"
        android:shrinkColumns="2">

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="test1"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="test2"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="test3"/>

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The first TableLayout has no mention of attribute for column2 and the second table layout has an explicit mention of attribute for column2 to be `columnShrink`. And both apparently give same output.

So, is it safe to assume that shrinkColumns is the default attribute even if not explicitly stated?

Answer (score 0):

With that amount of text at the default font size I would expect the same output.

As the TableLayout [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout) say

> The total width of the table is defined by its parent container.

So if you don't specify and grow/shrinkable it will grow/shrink them all equally to match the parent.

But in you case TableLayout will because you have only one row, it first sizes them to basically `wrap_content` and finds that this does not match the parent width and therefore it will grow column 0 and 1 equally to fill the space.

Because it is not short of space it (because it can grow) then it will never engage any shrink functionality because from the docs

> If marked as stretchable, it can expand in width to fit any extra space

The key word here is `extra`

You would only expect it shrink a column if the text sized at `wrap_content` is wider than the screen (and therefore no column will be grown)

So really `android:shrinkColumns="2"` on table is redundant and has no affect, the default of `wrap_content` will be used

Basically growing will never force any other column to shrink.